# How can you check the password complexity policy through the MS Graph Client?

Tags: azure-active-directory, passwords, microsoft-graph-api

I am successfully adding users to my AD tenant and giving them a role in my application.

```
                User newUser = new User
                {
                    DisplayName = $"{u.GivenName} {u.Surname}",
                    GivenName = u.GivenName,
                    JobTitle = u.JobTitle,
                    Mail = u.Mail,
                    MobilePhone = u.MobilePhone,
                    Surname = u.Surname,
                    AccountEnabled = true,
                    MailNickname = $"{u.GivenName}{u.Surname.Substring(0, 1)}",
                    UserPrincipalName = u.Mail,
                    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                    {
                        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
                        Password = u.Password
                    }
                };

                var user = await _graphServiceClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(newUser);
```

One issue I am running into is that if the password doesn't meet the complexity requirements, the AddAsync() will error out (natch) so I would like to check if the password meets the requirements before attempting to add the new user.

Does anyone know the syntax for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no** method of MS Graph to check your password before adding the user by design. You could use [**regex**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) to check passwords with complexity requirements as a workaround.

There are some requirements of [Azure AD password policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-policy#password-policies-that-only-apply-to-cloud-user-accounts) by default:

[image]

Comment: Not that familiar with Azure AD, is the password complexity configurable per tenant or is it a standard for all of Azure AD? Nevermind I read the link so it is mostly not configurable.

Comment: The properties in the screenshot are suitable for all users in Azure AD. And these three can't be modified.